# How to test redux-thunk middleware async functions?

Tags: mocha.js, sinon, redux, chai, redux-thunk

I'm trying to test my asyn **thunk middleware** function using **mocha, chai and sinon** (my first time!).

Please consider my files:

ayncActionCreators.js

```
export const fetchCurrentUser = () => {
   return (dispatch) => {
      setTimeout(dispatch, 100);
   }
};
```

ayncActionCreators.spec.js

```
//...
it('Should work', () => {
   const dispatch = sinon.spy();
   const action = fetchCurrentUser();

   action(dispatch);

   expect(dispatch.called).to.be.true;
});
```

I did not yet implement the fetchCurrentUser function - just assumed it will take some "server" time and then it will call 'dispatch()'.

The spec fails, due to the async flow. If I add a setTimeout of 101 ms before the expect - it passes.

My code will use some DB API that returns promise, so the async function will eventually look like:

```
//...
return (dispatch) => {
   return dbAPI.fetchUser().then(dispatch(....));
}
```

So I tried to require dbAPI and create a sinon.stub().returns(Promise.resolve()) inside the test and it didn't work as well (I thought that since the stub returns a resolved promise - the async function will act like a synchronous function).

Any ideas how should I test async functions like that?

Thank,
Amit.

Answer (score 5):

Don't mock dispatch with sinon, write your own and call Mocha's [`done()`](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) in that when it's done.

```
it('Should work', (done) => {
   const dispatch = () => {
     // Do your tests here
     done();
   };
   const action = fetchCurrentUser();

   action(dispatch)
     // Also allow quick failures if your promise fails
     .catch(done);
})
```

If you're just wanting to ensure that the dispatch is called, then mocha will time out.  The catch on the returned promise from your async action creator allows errors to be shown in the right place and for the test to fail rather than time out.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think I've found a solution:

Assuming my async function looks like this:

```
//...
return (dispatch) => {
   return dbAPI.fetchUser().then(dispatch(....));
}
```

Then I can write the spec as follows:

```
it('Should work', () => {
   dbAPI.fetchUser = sinon.stub().returns(Promise.resolve({username: 'John'}));

   const dispatch = sinon.spy();
   const action = fetchCurrentUser();

   action(dispatch).then(() => {
      expect(dispatch.called).to.be.true;
   });
});
```

I don't know if this is a workaround or not, but it works. I would appreciate your opinions of a better way of doing this...

Thanks,
Amit.

Comment: This is one of the unfortunate downsides of executing async effects in action creators, they are very difficult to test. If sticking with redux-thunk is your only option then this seems like the most concise way to run your tests. There are a number of other libraries for doing async things with redux that help to improve testability and not require you to mock your API if you're able to make a change, though

Comment: If all you want to do is ensure that the dispatch is called, then this will work.  If you want to test what dispatch gets called with (which is probably more meaningful) then you can use mocha's `done()` function and write your own dispatch as I've detailed in my answer.